# What effects do inductors have on circuits?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, batteries, inductance

[image: Example circuit]

The above diagram is a simple circuit containing an inductor.

According to the right hand grip rule, it can be deduced that the magnetic field is to the right. But the magnetic field produced by the current flowing through the inductor will induce an opposing current thanks to Lenz's law.

Does it mean that the current will be reduced by the inductor? What effects do inductors have on circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inductors only play a part in a circuit if the current through them is **changing** and then the act ny producing an emf so as to try and oppose the change.
If the current through an inductor is increasing/decreasing then the inductor will try and reduce the rate of increase/decrease of current.